# Infinite scroll change parameter

Tags: 7, ajax

My question is about drupal7 and infinite scroll module.
When I click on a button more news is loaded and html changes like this:

```
<ul class="pager pager--infinite-scroll ">
  <li class="pager__item">
    <a href="/about/media?page=1">Load More</a>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

My browser makes ajax request and receive some response:

```
view_name:blog
view_display_id:page
view_args:
view_path:about/media
view_base_path:about/media
view_dom_id:a2acec59ca7b252cfd911b770bc558bc
pager_element:0
page:2
```

I need to change `page` on frontend. How can I find where is this parameters set? OR can I change him on front end. I assume there is some hidden div related to this parameter, but I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If it helps: this is a view. You can access views list from `/admin/structure/views`  and  that specific view from `/admin/structure/views/view/blog/edit/page`

There you'll be able to change the output of page display.